# Valid format of /vue.config.js in vue/cli

Tags: vuejs2, config

I neeed some config file in @vue/cli 4.0.5 app and I created manually 
/vue.config.js with lines :

```
export const settingsTestriorityLabels = [
  { key: 0, label: 'No00000' },
  { key: 1, label: 'Lowwwwwww' }
]
```

But trying to use it in my component I got error :

```
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: 'settingsTestriorityLabels' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src/views/Tasks/TasksSelection.vue:66:8:
  64 | <script>
  65 | import appMixin from '@/appMixin'
> 66 | import settingsTestriorityLabels from './../../../vue.config.js'
     |        ^
  67 | // vue.config.js
  68 | export default {

but in my component settingsTestriorityLabels declared and used, like :

<template>
  <div class="hello">

    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    TasksSelection.vue +++++++
      settingsTestriorityLabels::{{ settingsTestriorityLabels }}

</template>

<script>
import appMixin from '@/appMixin'
import settingsTestriorityLabels from './../../../vue.config.js'
export default {
```

Is this configuration invalid ?

**MODIFIED # 2 :**
after break I remade my component and run

```
npm run serve
again but got error in my config file :
s$ npm run serve

> ctasks@0.1.0 serve /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/VApps/ctasks
> vue-cli-service serve

 ERROR  Error loading vue.config.js:
 ERROR  SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/VApps/ctasks/vue.config.js:1
export const settingsTestriorityLabels = [
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
```

I removed export key having in vue.config.js:

```
const settingsTestriorityLabels = [
  { key: 0, label: 'No00000' },
  { key: 1, label: 'Lowwwwwww' }
]
```

Is it valid format of vue.config.js?

Anyway I got the same error :

```
./src/views/Tasks/TasksSelection.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: 'settingsTestriorityLabels' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src/views/Tasks/TasksSelection.vue:66:10:
  64 | <script>
  65 | import appMixin from '@/appMixin'
> 66 | import { settingsTestriorityLabels } from './../../../vue.config.js'
     |          ^
  67 | // vue.config.js
  68 | export default {
```

My component content :

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">

    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
      settingsTestriorityLabels::{{ settingsTestriorityLabels }}
        ...
</template>

<script>
import appMixin from '@/appMixin'
import { settingsTestriorityLabels } from './../../../vue.config.js'
export default {

  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0,

      settingsTestriorityLabels: [],
```

I do not see why error and how to fix it as settingsTestriorityLabels is imported and defined ?

**MODIFIED # 3 :**
I found in net examples I tried to fill my vue.config.js with contentL

```
module.exports = {
  settingsTaskPriorityLabels: [
    { key: 0, label: 'No' },
    { key: 1, label: 'Low' },
    { key: 2, label: 'Medium' },
    { key: 3, label: 'High' },
    { key: 4, label: 'Urgent' },
    { key: 5, label: 'Immediate' }
  ]
}
```

and got errors:

```
$ npm run serve

> ctasks@0.1.0 serve /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/VApps/ctasks
> vue-cli-service serve

 ERROR  Invalid options in vue.config.js: "settingsTaskPriorityLabels" is not allowed
```

I tried some more examples, but failed all...

**MODIFIED # 4 :**
I created ./app.settings.js with content :

```
settingsTaskPriorityLabels = [
  { key: 0, label: 'No' },
  { key: 1, label: 'Low' },
  { key: 2, label: 'Medium' },
  { key: 3, label: 'High' },
  { key: 4, label: 'Urgent' },
  { key: 5, label: 'Immediate' }
]

settingsJsMomentDatetimeFormat = 'Do MMMM, YYYY h:mm A'
```

But got errors :

```
 error  in ./app.settings.js

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: 'settingsTaskPriorityLabels' is not defined (no-undef) at app.settings.js:1:1:
> 1 | settingsTaskPriorityLabels = [
    | ^
  2 |   { key: 0, label: 'No' },
  3 |   { key: 1, label: 'Low' },
  4 |   { key: 2, label: 'Medium' },


error: 'settingsJsMomentDatetimeFormat' is not defined (no-undef) at app.settings.js:10:1:
   8 | ]
   9 | 
> 10 | settingsJsMomentDatetimeFormat = 'Do MMMM, YYYY h:mm A'
     | ^
  11 |
```

Which syntax is valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a variable in data(){} then setting it equal to settingsTestriorityLabels

Are you sure you are importing correctly? I think you should change your import to

```
import { settingsTestriorityLabels } from ....
```

and

```
data() {
    return {
        ...
        testVar: settingsTestriorityLabels
    }
}
```

And then in the template

```
{{testVar}}
```

But I don't think that the vue.config.js file is where you should put your settingsTestriorityLabels setting, you can create another file to store these and import it. The vue.config.js file is for adding some configurations for @vue/cli when you build or test. Please have a look here https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config

Comment: pLease, look MODIFIED # 2

Comment: @mstdmstd just saw it and updated to show how I meant

Comment: Thank you, that is clear with defintion of settingsTestriorityLabels in my component, but what is still unclear for me that is format of vue.config.js file. Asgot error in console or running npm run serve command. Please example how that file can be.

Comment: @mstdmstd If I am not sure I understand your question. Do you still get an a error even now? Anyway, the vue.config.js file is optional as explained here https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config, the file is used to "inspect or modify the global CLI config". I am not really sure what that means but essentially you use it to configure your build if you are not comfortable with the default build behavior.

Comment: I need some example of not empty vue.config.js file, with several parameters like const settingsTestriorityLabels...

Comment: @mstdmstd ok, I see, take a look at the link I gave, there are examples in there

Comment: I see link https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config with empty cheme. Any other ?

Comment: @mstdmstd that is the main/official documentation on vue config. Or you can just google for "vue.config.js examples". Perhaps if you could explain how exactly you want to use settingsTestriorityLabels I could point you in the right direction

Comment: Pls, look MODIFIED # 3 :

Comment: @mstdmstd yes, the error ERROR Invalid options in vue.config.js: "settingsTaskPriorityLabels" is not allowed


means that the configuration has something that does not belong to vue. Which is why i had mention that you create another different file not "vue.config.js" to put YOUR settings. Just create a file like say mysettings.js and put your code in there.

Comment: Pls, look MODIFIED # 4

Comment: @mstdmstd you forgot let or var or const before settingTaskPriorityLables = […]